# jquery ui tooltip wierd behaviour when word is in different line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am implementing the jquery ui tooltip. It works very well however, when the element that I am hovering over is in 2 different lines it is going to the middle of the them....Is there any way to customize this behaviour?

I know one possibility is to use  `track:true`  I do not want to use this...

[Here is my jsfiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw36z/)

"Spice Girls" is the tooltip with weird behaviour.

```
$(function () {
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".oolinks",

    tooltipClass: "tooltip-position",
    content: function () {
        return "<div class='hi'>Hi There.</div>";
    },
    position: {
        my: "bottom-20",
        at: "top",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
            $(this).css(position);
            $("<div>")
                .addClass("arrow")
                .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                .appendTo(this);
            $('.ui-tooltip-content').click(function (e, ui) {

            });
        }
    },
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not relocate br tag in like here:

```
<strong>The <br/><culink class="oolinks" lang="en" href="http://undefined/en/topic/Spice Girls" style="color:rgb(34, 34, 34)!important;font-size:15px!important;font-weight:bold!important;border-bottom-color:#4de3ce!important">Spice Girls</culink> </strong>about going on a joint<br/>international tour.
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the <br/>  only for my  example. Sometimes the String will be cut in two lines even if there is no <br/>...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is apply two tooltips for each word ie., 'Spice' and 'Girls'.

```
<strong>The <culink class="oolinks" lang="en" href="http://undefined/en/topic/Spice Girls" style="color:rgb(34, 34, 34)!important;font-size:15px!important;font-weight:bold!important;border-bottom-color:#4de3ce!important">Spice </culink> <culink class="oolinks" lang="en" href="http://undefined/en/topic/Spice Girls" style="color:rgb(34, 34, 34)!important;font-size:15px!important;font-weight:bold!important;border-bottom-color:#4de3ce!important">Girls </culink> </strong>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw36z/2/).